# JBOSS 6.1 unable to get connection from pool

Tags: java, jboss, jboss6.x, hornetq

I am unable to get a connection from pool and JBOSS ends up throwing the below exception. I'm using JBOSS v6.1. Any pointer would be much appreciated. Thanks.

NOTE: Stackoverflow limits body by 30,000 characters. To see the entire stacktrace below is the pastebin link. Thanks.

http://pastebin.com/SHZ38WVi

```
10:39:39,011 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener] {} (Thread-1432 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1216468300)) IJ000305: Connection error occured: org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@ecf12e5[state=NORMAL managed connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection@3ce17ffb connection handles=0 lastUse=1399905579009 trackByTx=true pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@33da1194 pool internal context=SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool@1f7132ea[pool=wowDatasource] xaResource=XAResourceWrapperImpl@789956f6[xaResource=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection@3ce17ffb pad=false overrideRmValue=false productName=Oracle productVersion=Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
    With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, OLAP and Data Mining options jndiName=java:jboss/datasources/wowDatasource] txSync=null]: oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAException
        at oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAResource.checkError(OracleXAResource.java:1110) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXAResource.start(OracleXAResource.java:240) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection.start(XAManagedConnection.java:259)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.tx.jbossts.XAResourceWrapperImpl.start(XAResourceWrapperImpl.java:191)
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.enlistResource(TransactionImple.java:636)
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.enlistResource(TransactionImple.java:397)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener$TransactionSynchronization.enlist(TxConnectionListener.java:607)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener.enlist(TxConnectionListener.java:265)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.managedConnectionReconnected(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:467)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.reconnectManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:599)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:467)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:139)
        at org.company.wow.phone.data.PhoneOffice.onMessage(PhoneOffice.java:104) [wow-phone-ejb-1.0.jar:]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:58) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:58) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:226) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:317) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:214) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:55) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.messagedriven.MessageDrivenComponentDescription$5$1.processInvocation(MessageDrivenComponentDescription.java:196) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:182) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at javax.jms.MessageListener$$$view5.onMessage(Unknown Source) [jboss-jms-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.inflow.MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.doInvoke(MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.java:140) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.inflow.AbstractInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandler.java:73) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.onMessage(Unknown Source)
        at org.hornetq.ra.inflow.HornetQMessageHandler.onMessage(HornetQMessageHandler.java:313)
        at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.callOnMessage(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1085)
        at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.access$400(ClientConsumerImpl.java:57)
        at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl$Runner.run(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1220)
        at org.hornetq.utils.OrderedExecutorFactory$OrderedExecutor$1.run(OrderedExecutorFactory.java:106)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]

    10:39:39,019 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.jta] {} (Thread-1432 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1216468300)) ARJUNA016061: TransactionImple.enlistResource - XAResource.start returned: XAException.XAER_RMFAIL for < formatId=131077, gtrid_length=29, bqual_length=36, tx_uid=0:ffff0a057d2b:7e2be3cc:536d2ebb:157db, node_name=1, branch_uid=0:ffff0a057d2b:7e2be3cc:536d2ebb:157e7, subordinatenodename=null, eis_name=java:jboss/datasources/wowDatasource >: oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAException
        at oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAResource.checkError(OracleXAResource.java:1110) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXAResource.start(OracleXAResource.java:240) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection.start(XAManagedConnection.java:259)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.tx.jbossts.XAResourceWrapperImpl.start(XAResourceWrapperImpl.java:191)
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.enlistResource(TransactionImple.java:636)
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.enlistResource(TransactionImple.java:397)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener$TransactionSynchronization.enlist(TxConnectionListener.java:607)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener.enlist(TxConnectionListener.java:265)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.managedConnectionReconnected(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:467)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.reconnectManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:599)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:467)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:139)
        at org.company.wow.phone.data.PhoneOffice.onMessage(PhoneOffice.java:104) [wow-phone-ejb-1.0.jar:]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:58) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:58) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:226) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:317) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:214) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:55) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.messagedriven.MessageDrivenComponentDescription$5$1.processInvocation(MessageDrivenComponentDescription.java:196) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:182) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at javax.jms.MessageListener$$$view5.onMessage(Unknown Source) [jboss-jms-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.1.Final-redhat-2]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.inflow.MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.doInvoke(MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.java:140) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.inflow.AbstractInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandler.java:73) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.onMessage(Unknown Source)
        at org.hornetq.ra.inflow.HornetQMessageHandler.onMessage(HornetQMessageHandler.java:313)
        at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.callOnMessage(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1085)
        at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.access$400(ClientConsumerImpl.java:57)
        at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl$Runner.run(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1220)
        at org.hornetq.utils.OrderedExecutorFactory$OrderedExecutor$1.run(OrderedExecutorFactory.java:106)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]

    10:39:39,024 ERROR [stderr] {} (Thread-1432 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1216468300)) oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAException
    10:39:39,024 ERROR [stderr] {} (Thread-1432 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1216468300))     at oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAResource.checkError(OracleXAResource.java:1110)
    10:39:39,025 ERROR [stderr] {} (Thread-1432 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1216468300))     at oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXAResource.start(OracleXAResource.java:240)
    10:39:39,025 ERROR [stderr] {} (Thread-1432 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1216468300))     at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection.start(XAManagedConnection.java:259)
    10:39:39,025 ERROR [stderr] {} (Thread-1432 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1216468300))     at org.jboss.jca.core.tx.jbossts.XAResourceWrapperImpl.start(XAResourceWrapperImpl.java:191)
    10:39:39,025 ERROR [stderr] {} (Thread-1432 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1216468300))     at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.enlistResource(TransactionImple.java:636)
    10:39:39,025 ERROR [stderr] {} (Thread-1432 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1216468300))     at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.enlistResource(TransactionImple.java:397)
    10:39:39,026 ERROR [stderr] {} (Thread-1432 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1216468300))     at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener$TransactionSynchronization.enlist(TxConnectionListener.java:607)
    10:39:39,026 ERROR [stderr] {} (Thread-1432 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1216468300))     at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener.enlist(TxConnectionListener.java:265)
    10:39:39,026 ERROR [stderr] {} (Thread-1432 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1216468300))     at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.managedConnectionReconnected(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:467)
    10:39:39,026 ERROR [stderr] {} (Thread-1432 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1216468300))     at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.reconnectManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:599)
    10:39:39,026 ERROR [stderr] {} (Thread-1432 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1216468300))     at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:467)
    10:39:39,027 ERROR [stderr] {} (Thread-1432 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1216468300))     at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:139)
    10:39:39,027 ERROR [stderr] {} (Thread-1432 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1216468300))     at org.company.wow.phone.data.PhoneOffice.onMessage(PhoneOffice.java:104)
    10:39:39,027 ERROR [stderr] {} (Thread-1432 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1216468300))     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    10:39:39,027 ERROR [stderr] {} (Thread-1432 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1216468300))     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    10:39:39,028 ERROR [stderr] {} (Thread-1432 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1216468300))     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    10:39:39,028 ERROR [stderr] {} (Thread-1432 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1216468300))     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    10:39:39,028 ERROR [stderr] {} (Thread-1432 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1216468300))     at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory.java:72)
    10:39:39,028 ERROR [stderr] {} (Thread-1432 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1216468300))     at
```

....

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in my scenario I was using distributed transactions. I had 2 datasources which used 2 different service names. But both services pointed to the same database. And Oracle complained about that. If you are using 2 different services they must have 2 different databases.

Comment: I've managed to reproduce this problem with jboss transactions (narayana, standalone, 5.0.3.Final). But the problem is not reproducable with atomikos and bitronix. So I think this is not an oracle limitation. I wonder why I may not wish to make coordinated changes to 2 schemas on one server instance... Are there any known workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time researching this problem and decided to log the results as an answer.
First of all this behavior is permanent in jboss/narayana and does not exists in atomikos, bitronix and weblogic jta-implementations.
In accordance with comments in http://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBTM-2264 these jta-implementations have different handling of detecting duplicate XAResources (pointer comparison / calling isSameRM method;
using `isSameRM` method is the required way of checking for RM equality as defined in the JTA specification).
The difference is eliminated "in-the-box" by overriding mentioned method in jboss JCA. So out-of-the-box the problem still exists (Narayana 5.0.3.Final).